# ¿Cómo pasar data en la url en una petición POST usando express?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Tengo una duda, necesito una ruta tipo POST que reciba unos datos, los cuales los mando por body y recibo de la siguiente manera:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  let body = req.body;
  ...
});
```

Sé que puedo mandar datos por url de la siguiente manera:

```
app.post('/test/:id/:nombre', function(req, res) {
  let id = req.params.id;
  let nombre = req.params.nombre;
});
```

Funciona bien, pero lo que necesito es algo como:

```
/test/nombre=Akko?edad=100000?pais=mexico
```

¿Es esto posible? ¿Cual sería la manera de hacerlo?

Comment: la petición es desde el mismo endpoint ?

Comment: No, la API es pública y se consume desde distintos lugares. ¿O a qué te refieres?

Comment: Las mejores prácticas indican que si vas a usar un método `POST` no tiene sentido pasar parámetros por la URL, para eso está diseñado el método `GET`

Answer (score 2):

Parece que lo que tratas de hacer es mandar los parámetros a través de ["query string"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) 
. Para acceder a los parametros por "query string" solo necesitas obtenerlos de `req.query`

Te dejo el siguiente ejemplo:

> Petición: /test?nombre=Akko&&edad=100000&&pais=mexico

```
/**
 * Main file
 */

// Dependencies
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Initialize the server
const app = express();
// Port
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Routes
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  const { nombre, edad, pais } = req.query;
  res.status(200).send({ nombre, edad, pais });
});

// Run the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('server on port', port);
});
```